# background-color does not fill entire cell in menu

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-color

The background color in my navigation bar isn't filling the entire cell. Their is a line at the bottom of the menu that remains the color of the background of the page itself. How do i fill entire cell with background color correctly?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAh2d/1466/) i made to test it out. I'm new to JSFiddle so im not sure how long the link stays active.

CSS

```
.hovermenu ul {
 font: bold 20px Tahoma;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 height: 20px;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:red;
}

.hovermenu ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;         
}
.hovermenu li ul { display: none; }
.hovermenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  padding: 2px 0.5em;
}
.hovermenu ul li a:hover 
{
background-color:#fdff30;
border-style: outset; 
 }
.hovermenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.hovermenu li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.hovermenu li:hover a { background: #EEEEEE; }
.hovermenu li:hover li a:hover { background: #fdff30; }
html>body .hovermenu ul li a:active{ /* Apply mousedown effect only to NON IE browsers */
border-style: inset;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="hovermenu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/inventory.html">Inventory</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="/Trucks/main.html">Trucks</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.html">Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.html">Trailers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you cleared all the padding and margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to you are limiting the LI height with 20px, just remove that line from your css and it will work fine.

Comment: Awesome. Preciate the help.